# The Admin folder is not created after the installation

Tags: installation

Currently I am installing [Postleaf](https://www.postleaf.org/) but I have problems with the installation. When installing, it is successfully created the database, but the Admin folder, is not creating as shown in the following figure:

[image]

I could be doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: This belongs on [super user](http://superuser.com) and not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Cory here (creator of Postleaf). You won't see an admin folder because Postleaf uses a router. That is, all requests get passed through `index.php` and the appropriate response is served.

If everything goes well with your installation, you should get redirected to your admin panel at `example.com/admin`. However, Postleaf is still very new (it just launched a couple days ago) and there are some edge case bugs with the installer.

If you go to `/admin` and it's not loading, chances are your install failed for some reason. You can try installing it again by:

1. Deleting `database.php`
2. Grabbing the latest version from [postleaf.org/download](https://www.postleaf.org/download) (a patch was released a few hours ago)
3. Re-running the installer

If it still doesn't work, please post the relevant section of your PHP error log to help me identify the issue :)

Comment: You should document the redirects in the "Installation" section of your `INSTALL.md`, methinks --- not all server setups use `.htaccess` (e.g. I use NginX and because it's a hidden file, I didn't even notice it was there). Even Apache blocks it by default.

Comment: True. There are additional installations instructions for Apache, NGINX, and Caddy located here: https://www.postleaf.org/docs

Answer (score 0):

The requested URL /proiecte/temp/postleaf-1.0.0-beta7/admin was not found on this server.

The requested URL /proiecte/temp/postleaf-1.0.0-beta7/admin/posts/new was not found on this server.

Comment: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.